# How to create a pygame savefile

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a game with pygame and I'm still quite new to the programming language.
I tried making data/savefile with file i/o with text file with python (readlines and etc).
I realized, I can't erase a certain line and edit that line with file i/o with text files.
So I was wondering how I can create one either with file i/o (another way) or something integrated with pygame maybe?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Game Dev Stack Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), since you're looking to save game state specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You should use some kind of serialization where you save your game state (object) in a defined format that you can read in later, so it gets converted to a Python object again. For instance you can use the [shelve module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) or the [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) for implementing object persistence.